# Default options GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm working on Linux with C on this file:

```
#include "headerFiles.h"

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0
#define BUFSIZE 256
#define SERVER_PORT 8887

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

    int ls; // listen socket
    int s;  // descrittore socket
    int n;  // byte letti inviati
    int waitSize; // massimo numero persone in coda

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;

    int clientAddrLen = sizeof( clientAddr );

    memset(&serverAddr,0,sizeof(serverAddr));

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    if( (ls = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0) {

        perror("Errore: creazione della socket di asolto fallita!");
        exit(1);
    }

    int so_reuseaddr = TRUE;

    if( fork() == 0) {

        //---------------------------------------------------//
        //CODICE
        while (1) {

            char cmd[BUFSIZE];
            char var1[BUFSIZE];
            char var2[BUFSIZE];
            char string[100];

            memset(cmd, 0, sizeof(cmd));
            memset(var1, 0, sizeof(var1));
            memset(var2, 0, sizeof(var2));
            memset(string, 0, sizeof(string));
        }
    }

    close(s);
    exit(0);
}
```

This code represent a mini-Server on C but I have this problem:
How do I check if I have default gcc compiler options?

Because, for example, on Mac I get some warnings and on Linux not.

UPDATE:

for compile I use this makefile:

```
elaborato: *.c *.h
    gcc *.c -o elaborato
```

and when I execute it I do: `./elaborato`

I want to compile this program using default gcc settings.
it's enough this?

Comment: If you don't specify an option, then you get the default, correct?

Comment: C has built-in boolean type and constants for true and false. Do not define some homebrew stuff!

Comment: OS-X does not use gcc anymore, but clang. The gcc call is just a link to clang. Anyway, if you get warnings, you should not change compiler setting (always enable warnings!), but pay heed to them and fix your code. That does **not** mean wildly casting!

Comment: You might want to consider updating your question to show us the warnings.

Comment: I updated question when I explain better

Comment: Please read @KeithThompson s comment carefully again. Note that you should always enable **at least* `-Wall -Wextra` and likely `-Wconversion`, too. C allows to shoot your foot, so for many potential problems you will just get warnings, and a lot of them only when explicitly enabled.

Comment: you should read the man page for signal, especially: *The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also var‐
       ied historically across different versions of Linux.   Avoid  its  use:
       use sigaction(2) instead.*

Comment: the posted code is missing several key system function calls to be a server program.,  Calls like `setsockopt()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, `accept()`

Comment: @Olaf, I've never known C to have a built-in `bool`, `true`, `false`  (unless the compiler was specialized for some architecture that has bit addressable characteristics, like the 8051 family of microprocessors.)  However, it does have the header file that can be #include'd: `stdbool.h`

Comment: please post the contents of `headerfiles.h`

Comment: Surprisingly languages evolve. Even C gets a new standard from time to time. I'm afraid when programming, you have to learn permanently new stuff.

Comment: @user3629249: Starting with the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), C has a built-in Boolean type called `_Bool`, and a standard header `<stdbool.h>` that defines `bool`, `false`, and `true`. `_Bool` is not a 1-bit type. Its size is at least one byte, but converting any value to `_Bool` yields `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 5):

One thing to note is that most likely your gcc versions are different.  If you run gcc -v you'll see the flags that are enabled on your system.  For example:

```
gcc -v -o t9 t9.c
```

Shows a bunch of lines like this for me:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" \
-cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.10.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage \
-emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name t9.c \
-mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose \
-munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 253.2 -v -dwarf-column-info \
-resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.0 \
-fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/bruce/test -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 193 \
-stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.10.0 \
-fencode-extended-block-signature -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option \
-fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/kl/kz62dj0j3zx7zvdgs7w005_w0000gn/T/t9-e101bb.o -x c t9.c
clang -cc1 version 7.0.0 based upon LLVM 3.7.0svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
```

Except that the options are all on one very long line, not wrapped as shown here.

Comment: MacOS does not use gcc anymore (as the version shows).

Comment: And why do you provide a source and object file just to get the version? `gcc -v` is enough.

Comment: @olaf if you just do gcc -v you get the gcc configuration settings, but not the compiler flags.  I wanted to show him what compiler flags would show up.

Comment: You **did** notice that is not gcc. did you? On gcc `-v` is sufficient. Just checked clang: it apparently needs a source file with that option. So there we already have different behaviour. (you still don't need the `-o xxx` option btw.)

Comment: @olaf I know.  :)  I was too lazy to start up my Linux VM.  I used the -o option so I didn't get an a.out.  Those are so ugly!!!

Comment: `-o /var/folders/kl/kz62dj0j3zx7zvdgs7w005_w0000gn/T/t9-e101bb.o` looks quite insane to me - some Jersey-thing (sorry for being Southpark-ish), I suppose. On my Linux, that is just `-o a.out`, as one would expect (and that can easily be `rm`ed for a test). (clang, btw.).

Comment: @Olaf: The OP says he's working on Linux and Mac — with warnings on Mac and not on Linux.  It isn't clear where he's currently got problems — it is probably both but could be either.  This technique works with both clang and gcc.  There is a program gcc on the Mac, but it is (as the output shows) a masquerade — it's really `clang`.  But that's probably what the OP's using on the Mac. (The temporary directory on Mac's is obscure and long-winded.  On my Mac, at the moment, my `TMPDIR=/var/folders/lj/kt7909lm8xj2tl001s6z265r0000gq/T/`, which is very similar.  It's just different.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: So much for "looking and quacking like a duck" ... . I just wondered about the strange `-o` path. Yes, I know MacOS uses clang since some time now and fakes gcc. I just thought they show the same information with `-v` until I check myself (not used to clang so far), therefore my comment. Seems nonsense to me clang requires an actual file to provide this extended information, but actually I don't care.

Answer (score 5):

For GCC on Linux:

```
> gcc -Q --help=target
```

will produce list of options with enabled|disabled flag

Comment: That only lists targetr-specific options, not other defaults. `gcc -v` is the correct for these.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, `gcc` is probably a symlink to `clang`, which is a different compiler. Try to get your code working with `gcc -Wall -Werror`, then there should be no problems on your Mac either :)

*Edit:* Incorporating Olaf's objections, passing `-Wall` may reduce the warning level if an even higher level (like `-Wextra`) is set by default. The  flags that will be used by default can be checked with `gcc -v`, which is how you can verify this.
Another thing to note is that `-Werror` does of course not change the warning level, but rather treat all warnings as errors. Hence, if the compiler outputs any warnings, your code will not compile.

Comment: Reducing warnings is certainly not good advice. Better is to fix the code properly.

Comment: @Olaf, do you have any idea what the flags actually do?

Comment: Which flags do you mean? If you mean the options: Well enough to note that `-Werror` does not change the set of warnings, but just makes them errors. That is a matter of preference and whether you generate early stage debug code which might allow some warnings or late debug or release code which should not. Also `-Wextra -Wconversion` should actually be used.

Comment: Well, `-Wall` is usually good enough. Still I'd like to see where I advised OP to "reduce warnings", since `-Wall -Werror` flags are really quite helpful in doing what you mentioned: Fixing the code properly.

Comment: Please read my comment carefully. `-Werror` does not change the set of warnings, so it is useless for that. And **at least** `-Wextra` is strongly recommended. `-Wconversion` might be disputable, if you are not used to write signedness-clean code. But if you don't you better don't apply for a job in some industries or for advanced embedded programming. There might be some more options, but the three given are a good starter.

Comment: @Olaf, I know very well what all those options do, and it is good practice to use strict checks for sure. Still, you blamed me for advising OP to reduce warnings, and I didn't do that.

Comment: You do not know which default settings are enabled, so it might very well reduce warning level. Anyway, I give you bonus of doubt for now. Edit your text a bit so I can remove the DV.

Comment: Edited the post. I admit I did not think of the possibility that such a high warning level may be set by default, and I have never seen this to be honest. But yeah, in the end, you got a point here!